# Normal Matrix vs Diagonalizable Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I'm trying to understand the difference between a normal matrix ($A^TA = AA^T$) versus a matrix that can be diagonalized (let's stick with real matrices for this question).  In particular, does one of these concepts enclose the other:

- Is a diagonalizable matrix a subset of normal matrices?
- Or, is a normal matrix a subset of diagonalizable matrices?

Perhaps the answer depends on some nuance I haven't appreciated or they are interrelated in a way I haven't come across.  I have consulted a number of sources and I don't see a clear answer.  Can someone clarify this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices

Comment: There's a bunch of terms there I haven't yet mastered.  But, it says "One can show that A is normal if and only if it is unitarily diagonalizable" which seems to imply that normal is a subset of diagonalizable matrices.  Is that a proper interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every normal matrix is (unitarily) diagonalizable (a standard result), but not every diagonalizable matrix is normal.

If $S$ is an invertible matrix that is not unitary (i.e., $S^* \ne S^{-1}$) and $D$ is a diagonal matrix that does not commute with $S$, then $A := SDS^{-1}$ is diagonalizable but not normal.

Comment: Very technically your second statement is not true; consider $D$ a multiple of the identity. (More generally your statement will be false whenever $D$ commutes with $S$.)

Comment: Thank you.  The first sentence of your answer suggests that normal is a subset of diagonalizable.  Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: @Ian: edited—with thanks for alerting me to the error.

Comment: @BryanHanson: correct!

Answer (score 1):

Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\1&4\end{pmatrix}$ which is diagonalizable but not normal to see why first bullet is false.